# Gif not showing in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, gif

I'm trying to update a form and insert a gif loading image when a form  is submitted. The application I'm working on is built in Sharepoint and works using jQuery and AJAX. The gif image is not showing up in IE. It works fine in all other browsers. I can only get the image to appear in IE when I remove my submit function. My code is below. Any ideas what might be going on here? Thanks.

Form:

```
<div class='reply'>
//loader image
<div class='loader_gif'>
<img src='http://somesite.com/chat-zone/PublishingImages/loader.gif' />
</div>
//submit button
<a href='javascript: submitToCommentForm(" + QuestionID + ", " + ID + ");'>
<img src='/chat-zone/PublishingImages/reply.jpg' /></a>
</div>
```

The div.loader_gif is set to display:none. Here is the function called on submit:

```
function submitToCommentForm(commentID, articleID) {
//Show the loader   
$('div.loader_gif').css('display','block');
//Check that comment is valid and submit
    var title = $('div#questionscommentsForm-'+ commentID + ' TEXTAREA#replytext-'+ commentID).val();
    if (title == '' || title == 'Comment') { 
        $('.invalidmesssagecomment').show();
        $('div#questionscommentsForm-'+ commentID + ' TEXTAREA#replytext-'+ commentID).focus();
    } else { 
        // Run the create new comment function
        CreateNewthereadedcomment(commentID,title);
        updateCount(ArticleID);
    }
}
```

Comment: try with `addClass` and `removeClass`, or try with `$('.loader_gif')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.loader_gif').show();
```

would be better here.

http://api.jquery.com/show/